# get values from Json in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

good day guys!

I need your help please

I have this Json response from server

```
{
"1": [{
"unique_id": "5c8423926786f7.28263140",
"name": "Diego",
"email": "darasat@gmail.com",
"created_at": "2019-03-09 13:35:30",
"imagen": "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"
}]
}
```

how I can get the values in flutter in a field or variable?

thank you very much!

cheers

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
print(responseJson.nameAtribute);
```

I hope this can help you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dart object that represents your json.

Use [jsonDecode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) to parse json in a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Get data from `Map` and put in your object.

Take a look on documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: And that's a complex descendent... you'll have to drill down to that inner map with something like `yourdata["1"][0]`, so `yourdata["1"][0]["name"]` will be `Diego`.